# Python Read HDF5 Rows Where Index Not in List

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, dataframe, hdf5

I read a random subset of rows from an HDF table with the following Python/Pandas code:

```
hdf_store = pd.HDFStore('path_to_data.h5')
total_rows = hdf_store.get_storer('hdf_table_name').nrows

num_rows = int(total_rows * .25)
row_indices = np.random.randint(0,rows_indices,size=num_rows)

my_df = pd.read_hdf(hdf_store, 'hdf_table_name', where=pd.Index(row_indices))
```

Later in the program, I would like to pull the rest of the rows of data from the HDF5 table. But the following threw errors:

```
rest_of_rows = pd.read_hdf(hdf_store, 'hdf_table_name',
   where=pd.Index(not in (row_indices)))

rest_of_rows = pd.read_hdf(hdf_store, 'hdf_table_name',
   where=not pd.Index(row_indices))
```

Is there a way to pull HDF rows by records not in a list of indices?

Because the table is larger than my RAM, I would like to avoid pulling all the rows from HDF upfront (even in chunks) and then splitting it to hold both tables at once. I could map the indices to another column, and subset on rows not in the mapped value of that column. But that would presumably be a lot slower than querying on the index directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Index.difference](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.difference.html) method.

Demo:

```
# randomly select 25% of index elements (without duplicates `replace=False`)
sample_idx = np.random.choice(np.arange(total_rows), total_rows//4, replace=False)

# select remaining index elements
rest_idx = pd.Index(np.arange(total_rows)).difference(sample_idx)

# get rest rows by index
rest = store.select('hdf_table_name', where=rest_idx)
```

PS optionally you may want to select rest of rows in chunks...